# Run idle using pen drive python

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to import libraries from one devices to another or any way to run python idle from pen drive to any other device

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is not built into python normally but you could use [a portable install](https://portablepython.com/) this should allow python and all the libraries you install to be on a USB